# require.js for non-browser platform or the right way to use Function constructor

Tags: javascript, function, coffeescript, requirejs, apple-tv

I am trying to use `requirejs` in an Apple TV project. We have a lot of `requirejs` modules written for web, would be cool if we could re-use them.

Apple TV platform has certain limitations and it's sorta impossible to use requirejs "as is". There's no DOM in common sense. 
One possible way I found to overcome the problem is: first to load require.js itself and then override its `.load()` method, so whenever `require('foo')` gets called it would load `foo.js` via a simple XHR call:

```
 requirejs.load = (context, moduleName, moduleUrl) ->
    reqModule = new XMLHttpRequest()
    reqModule.open('GET', appRoot+moduleUrl, true)
    reqModule.send(null)
    reqModule.onreadystatechange = ->
     if reqModule.readyState is 4 and reqModule.status is 200
          fn = (new Function(reqModule.responseText))() # parse module                             
          context[moduleName] = fn
          context.completeLoad(moduleName)
```

So this works for normally defined modules like this:

```
  define [], ->
       someField: 'empty field'
```

Even works for self executing functions like this (with shim configured):

```
  (myFoo = ->
      someField:"empty field"
  )()
```

*for example `Undercore.js` contains itself in a self executing wrapper*

However, that doesn't work with modules defined like this:

```
 myFoo = ->
    someField:"empty field"
```

Question: how can I make it work for all 3 cases? When used in browser, requirejs successfully loads all of them.

One solution I found is to wrap the function in `define` block for non-wrapped modules like in the last example, so instead of doing  `fn = (new Function(reqModule.responseText))()` I would do:

```
fn = define [], (new Function("return "+reqModule.responseText))()
```

But then that would break `load` for both first and second cases. Is there a way to find out if a function wrapped in a self-executing block or not? How can I distinguish first two cases from the last one?

Comment: It is possible to use RequireJS in an environment with no DOM. For instance in Node.js. I don't know what JavaScript environment Apple TV provides so it's hard for me to be more precise.

Comment: If you look into the require.js code you'd see that for browser it injects a `script` tag, for non-browser environment it uses `webWorker`. Neither of this techniques unfortunately would work on AppleTV

Comment: You are looking in the wrong place. You have to look at `r.js`. Yes, I know it's the optimizer but it is *also* RequireJS' implementation for non-browser environments. If you do `npm install requirejs` you'll see that the `package.json` points to `bin/r.js`, and this file contains a copy of the code that you see in `require.js`. I use RequireJS in Node on a daily basis.

Comment: Louis, I'm gonna try and will let you know. If that works on ATV, you're gonna have to post it as an answer. Thanks

Comment: No unfortunately, r.js didn't work for me. I need something that can be loaded through XHR and `eval`ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code in the question as a starting point, I was able to get the following code to work. I don't have Apple TV so I cannot test it on Apple TV. I've tested it in a browser. It is able to load all 3 types of modules you've shown in your question, provided that the 2nd and 3rd modules have appropriate shims. So the logic is sound. The missing piece is what needs to stand in for `window` in `eval.call(window, ...)`. In Node.js, it would be `global`. I don't know the equivalent in Apple TV.

```
  requirejs.load = function(context, moduleName, moduleUrl) {
      var reqModule = new XMLHttpRequest();
      reqModule.open('GET', moduleUrl, true);
      reqModule.send(null);
      return reqModule.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (reqModule.readyState === 4 && reqModule.status === 200) {
              eval.call(window, reqModule.responseText);
              return context.completeLoad(moduleName);
          }
      };
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would use [Browserify](http://browserify.org)

> Write your browser code with node.js-style requires.

Comment: as I said, we have a lot of modules written in require.js style. Also I'm almost sure `browserify` won't work for AppleTV out of the box either.